# Swift , remove remove all character and keep only number

Tags: swift, string

I have a string in swift like below:

```
C/I               MFM    1110
```

is it possible to get only the number? I need to remove all the letter and keep only the number.

Thanks

Comment: I can think of about ten different ways to do it, actually.

Comment: Not really. I was thinking I might give an answer showing all of them. Just running over them in my mind now. — And none of them is the one Chip gave!

Comment: understood, apologies ..:)

Comment: Lol.. there are actually tons of ways to do it, and which ones seems most obvious depends on how you approach the problem, so it's not surprising that my solution isn't one you thought of.   I hope others will answer too, so OP can see how different people solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways, including regular expressions, but assuming that your example is representative of the format, whitespace-separated columns of text where you always want the last column, an easy way is

```swift
guard let numSubstr = s.split(whereSeparator: { $0.isWhitespace }).last else {
    fatalError("No columns!")
}

let numStr = String(numSubstr)
```

where `s` is the `String` from which you want to extract the last non-whitespace `Substring`.

If you know that there is only ever one number on the line (and that number is where the only digit characters are) you could also do:

```swift
let numStr = s.filter { $0.isNumber }
```

For more complicated or varying line formats, you'd probably need to use regular expressions or explicitly parse it character by character yourself.

Comment: thanks a lot, last option with isNumber more useful for me, since my number can change position on the string...

Comment: Glad it's useful!

Comment: String initializer is pointless there. When using the filter method on a String it returns a string. Btw `isNumber` would allow fraction characters as well

Comment: @LeoDabus, good catch!  For some reason my brain was thinking it would return `[Character]` as filter does with most other sequences, but you are correct, and I'll fix that in my answer.

Comment: There is a specific filter method on `RangeReplaceableCollection` which returns `Self`. String conforms to it. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rangereplaceablecollection/2908316-filter

Comment: As for `.isNumber` yes, it also allows some other numeric systems too (like Hiragana digits).  But both of my solutions make specific narrow assumptions about the source string anyway.   It's probably better to write one's own function (or extension on Character) to detect the specific legal characters one is looking for.

Comment: @ChipJarred `.filter { "0"..."9" ~= $0 }`

Comment: That works as an ad hoc solution.  If it's used in multiple places, even as simple as it is, I'd prefer to use that same test, but give a name, and put it in one place.  Then it can be extended, for example to include a decimal point, in just one source location.

Answer (score 0):

I take this as an opportunity to be very silly and have fun, so, without further ado...

```
    let s = "boomalaka boom12345zzz yoho"

    do {
        let sc = Scanner(string: s)
        _ = sc.scanUpToCharacters(from: .decimalDigits)
        if let result = sc.scanCharacters(from: .decimalDigits) {
            print(result)
        }
    }

    do {
        let r = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: #"\d+"#)
        if let match = r.firstMatch(in: s, options: [], range: NSRange(s.startIndex..<s.endIndex, in: s)) {
            if let range = Range(match.range, in: s) {
                let result = String(s[range])
                print(result)
            }
        }
    }

    do {
        let result = String(s.drop { !$0.isNumber }.prefix { $0.isNumber })
        print(result)
    }

    // import Algorithms, see swift-algorithms package

    do {
        let result = String(s.trimming { !$0.isNumber })
        print(result)
    }
    
    do {
        let result = s.filter { $0.isNumber }
        print(result)
    }
    
    do {
        if let st = s.firstIndex(where: { $0.isNumber }) {
            if let end = s[st...].firstIndex( where: { !$0.isNumber }) {
                let result = String(s[st..<end])
                print(result)
            }
        }
    }
    
    do {
        var arr = Array(s)
        arr = arr.filter { $0.isNumber }
        let result = arr.map(String.init).joined()
        print(result)
    }
    
    // import Algorithms
    
    do {
        var arr = Array(s)
        let ix = arr.stablePartition { $0.isNumber }
        let result = arr[ix...].map(String.init).joined()
        print(result)
    }
```

If you don't like the heavy use of `isNumber`, I would recommend a Set of Character and `.contains`.